# Special characters when reading in CSV file in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, read.csv

I downloaded a CSV file online. When I read in the CSV file with `read.csv()`, there are some special characters in the data. Here's an example:

```
I didn�t get the bread from the bakery.
```

Is there any argument I can add to the `read.csv` function so that it recognizes these special characters? I understand it may be an encoding UTF-8 issue, but I am not able to change the format in which I downloaded the data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give `fread()` a go to read in your csv. And adjust the encoding argument to read your file correctly. May need the `latin-1` encoding.

```
text <- fread(file, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

See if this helps with having empty fields as `NA`

```
text <- fread(file,encoding='UTF-8',fill=TRUE,na.strings="")
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This worked. However, is there a way to read in the empty cells as type NA with this solution?

Comment: Ah no worries! I got it. I used na.strings = c(NA_character_, "") as an argument if anyone's curious.

Comment: @jo_ i updated my answer with the NA fill also